# How to use column with tput colors?

Tags: bash, text-formatting, tput

Using tput colors seems to disturb the output of column.  Why does this happen and more importantly is there a way around it?

```
$ {
  echo "$(tput bold)foo$(tput sgr0)" "$(tput bold)bar$(tput sgr0)"
  echo bar foo
} | column -t
foo  bar
bar                     foo
```

I have reproduced this issue on both macos and ubuntu 20.04 although it seems they both use BSD column

Comment: There used to be a very similar question somewhere at SE a few months
ago. Anyway, the answer is the same: it works well for me with
`column from util-linux 2.36`. What implementation of `column` are you using?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk updated

Comment: Indeed, Ubuntu uses BSD implementation https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/util-linux/+bug/1705437. It seems quite weird to me, we have util-linux implementation on Slackware. Can't you just install `column` from util-linux?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk: I would prefer not to, this is going to be used on both macos and ubuntu docker containers so ultimately I would rather just remove the colors than require additional tools to be installed but I ideally I would like to get it working.

Comment: The [`util-linux`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/utils/util-linux/util-linux.git/tree/text-utils/column.c) code doesn't handle escape sequences for colors, making "works well for me" dubious.

Comment: @ThomasDickey: that's what I get https://i.imgur.com/yXDbQDo.png

Comment: It only works in certain limited cases such as OP's question.  In particular, if you exercise colors, you'll notice that it doesn't work.

Comment: IMO intermediate applications shouldn't be outputting colour codes

Answer (score 1):

You can pipe to `cat -v` to see all the characters of this file stream. `column` calculates the width using them:

```
^[[1mfoo^[(B^[[m ^[[1mbar^[(B^[[m
bar foo
```

---

The right way is to separate any content creation from any formatting (like the MVC model). Note that `column` is adding spaces to produce a tab-like output, so it modifies the content. While `tput` adds instructions to the terminal. By separating these tasks, we are able to save the output to a file, or pass it from our formatting function to send it to console, or format it for other destination.

---

But this is also a good exercise for `awk`, to implement `column -t` excluding some characters from the width calculations. The regular expression I use below catches a lot of `tput` stuff, but I am almost sure not all of them.

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    OFS = "  "
}

{
    nr = NR
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        f[NR,i] = $i
        gsub(/\x1B[^[:alpha:]]+[[:alpha:]]/,"",$i)
        if (length($i) > col[i]) col[i] = length($i)
    }
}

END {
    for (i=1;i<=nr;i++) {
        for (j=1;j<=length(col);j++) {
            printf "%-"col[j]"s%s", f[i,j], (j==length(col)? ORS : OFS)
        }
    }
}
```

and you pipe the first output to `awk -f tst.awk`

Answer (score 1):

```
$ {
    echo -e "$(tput bold)foo$(tput sgr0)" "$(tput bold)bar$(tput sgr0) baz";
    echo bar foo;
  } |cat -v
^[[1mfoo^[(B^[[m ^[[1mbar^[(B^[[m baz
bar foo
```

The problem is on `tput sgr0` that as you know by default `tputs` uses escapes codes based on the Terminal type taken from the environment variable `TERM`.

if you do:

```
infocmp -1 |grep -E 'bold|sgr0'
    bold=\E[1m,
    sgr0=\E(B\E[m,
```

You will see what **bold** and **sgr0** codes are (those are non-ANSI escapes values) which as you see in output after `cat -v` those converted to `^[[1m` for `tputs bold` and `^[(B^[[m` for `sgr0` and `column` command do the same and resolves to ANSI escape type codes but fails when there is `(B` and left in `^[(B^[[m` and then that doesn't recognized in ANSI escapes and caused final output not expected column-wise correctly.

if you do:

```
infocmp -1 -T ansi |grep -E 'bold|sgr0'
        bold=\E[1m,
        sgr0=\E[0;10m,
```

you will find the equivalent ANSI escape codes for each; so you have two options to resolve it:

1. Replace `tputs` with ANSI escape codes above

   ```
   { 
     echo -e "\033[1mfoo\033[0;10m" "\033[1mbar\033[0;10m baz";
     echo bar foo;
   } |column -t
   ```
2. Pass Terminal type to `tputs`:

   ```
   {
     echo -e "$(tput bold)foo$(tput -T ansi sgr0)" "$(tput bold)bar$(tput -T ansi sgr0) baz";
     echo bar foo;
   } |column -t
   ```

Comment: I tried the two proposals, I get the same result with the command in the question (`column from util-linux 2.33.1`) I see some comments under the question that some other implementations do not, do you reproduce the issue similar to the question? And I expect and see for my environment, the same result for `tput` or `echo -e`, as both would print the same output through `cat -v`.

Comment: @thanasisp Ohh, I'm using BSD `column`  exactly this version; https://www.commandlinux.com/man-page/man1/column.1.html, but I see the similar output as OP posted, and above given commands both fix the intention; also my Terminal is Windows10 CMD

Comment: and also note that with same version of `column` but Linux Terminal type everything is fine even with OP's sample or mine in answer. so that is related to Terminal Type itself as mentioned and need specify Terminal type to `tput` command

Answer (score 0):

I was running Ubuntu 18.04 and was puzzled by behaviour of `column` not acting as expected. As others have suggested, the problem is that the repo contains an antique.

The only way I found to obtain a modern version was by compiling from the [`util-linux` repo](https://github.com/util-linux/util-linux).

It was difficult to figure this out because `-V` to obtain the version had not yet been added! There might be a more elegant way but I inferred the approximate version by calling up `man column` which has a date at the bottom "July 29, 2004". Compare [the 2004 manpage](https://www.unix.com/man-page/linux/1/column/) to [the 2019 manpage](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/bsdextrautils/column.1.en.html). While the former describes only *four* options, the latter has almost *two dozen*!

I can also say that on MacOS Catalina I get exactly the same thing. I was unable to locate a `brew` package that contains a more recent version of `column` but it might be hidden somewhere.

If you are unable to obtain access to a modern version, you should make sure to check the man page corresponding to whatever is present otherwise things will be frustrating!